# What is causing items from UIPasteboard to be converted to NSConcreteMutableData?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uipasteboard

I'm running the following in a playground (I've tested in Xcode 7.3.1 as well as Xcode 8.1 and see the same behavior):

```
import UIKit

let key: String = "some_key"
let value: String = "some_value"

UIPasteboard.general.items = [[key: value]]

let item = UIPasteboard.general.items.first
if let item = UIPasteboard.general.items.first {
    switch item[key] {
    case let x as String:
        print("This is expected")
    case let x as Any:
        type(of: x)
        print("This is unexpected")
    default:
        print("This is unexpected")
    }
} else {
    print("This is unexpected")
}
```

And I notice that the `String` that I put into the pasteboard actually gets bridged back out as `NSConcreteMutableData`.

My questions are the following:

1. Is this caused by an internal UIPasteboard implementation (i.e. explicitly converting from `NSString` to `NSConcreteMutableData`), or is this standard ObjC-Swift bridging behavior?
2. How can I work around this to store custom key/value pairs in UIPasteboard?

Here's what this looks like in a playground, for easy reference:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Data` you get for `item[key]` is simply the UTF-8 encoded value for the string.

If you add the following `case`, you will see that:

```
case let x as Data:
    let str = String(data: x, encoding: .utf8)
    print("str = \(str)")
```

The cause of the confusion is that the keys used by the `items` property are UTIs, not random keys. If you change your key to `public.text` then your code will work as expected.

Normally, you would not put a string on the pasteboard using the `items` property. You would use the `string` property to read and write the value.

```
UIPasteboard.general.string = "Hello"
let aStr = UIPasteboard.general.string
print("aStr = \(aStr)")
```

Doing this avoids the need to specify a UTI and it avoids replacing all existing items on the pasteboard.

Comment: Note that if you `import MobileCoreServices`, you can use `kUTTypeText as String` as your key instead of hardcoding `"public.text"`, should you want to specify the UTI.